# SASS, when to extend?

Tags: css, sass

I'm currently working on a team that uses SASS. I see that we are extending styles that are very simple and to me I don't see the benefit of doing this. Am I missing something?

Here are some examples of a _Common.scss that is imported and used throughout other sass files:

```
.visibility-hidden{visibility: hidden;}
.display-inline { display: inline; }
.display-inline-block { display: inline-block; }
.display-block { display: block; }
.display-none { display: none; }
.display-box { display: box; }

.float-left { float: left; }
.float-right { float: right; }
.clear-both { clear: both; }

.width-percent-100 { width: 100%; }
.width-percent-65 { width: 65%; }
.width-percent-50 { width: 50%; }
.width-percent-45 { width: 45%; }
.width-percent-40 { width: 40%; }
.width-percent-33 { width: 33%; }
.width-percent-30 { width: 30%; }
.width-percent-20 { width: 20%; }

.height-percent-100 { height: 100%; }

.cursor-pointer { cursor: pointer; }

.underline { text-decoration: underline; }
.text-decoration-none { text-decoration: none; }
.bold { font-weight: bold; }
.font-weight-normal { font-weight: normal; }
.text-align-center { text-align: center; }
.text-align-left { text-align: left; }
.text-align-right { text-align: right; }

.font-10 { font-size: 10px; }
.font-11 { font-size: 11px; }
.font-12 { font-size: 12px; }
.font-13 { font-size: 13px; }
.font-14 { font-size: 14px; }
.font-15 { font-size: 15px; }
.font-16 { font-size: 16px; }
.font-17 { font-size: 17px; }
.font-18 { font-size: 18px; }

.font-percent-65 { font-size: 65%; }
.font-percent-80 { font-size: 80%; }
.font-percent-90 { font-size: 90%; }
.font-percent-100 { font-size: 100%; }
.font-percent-110 { font-size: 110%; }
.font-percent-120 { font-size: 120%; }
.font-percent-130 { font-size: 130%; }
.font-percent-140 { font-size: 140%; }
.font-percent-150 { font-size: 150%; }
.font-percent-160 { font-size: 160%; }
.font-percent-170 { font-size: 170%; }
.font-percent-180 { font-size: 180%; }
```

Example:

```
#CategoriesContainer
{
  ul{
    li{
        &:first-child{
          @extend .font-11;
        }
        a
        {
          @extend .font-11;
          @extend .text-decoration-none;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't comment on why this decision was made, but from the looks of it, it's just sheer stupidity.

Comment: Thsi indeed doesn't seem to make any sense at all. The point of CSS classes is to create semantic hierarchies, not hard-coded values

Comment: Ill edit the post with an example of when it gets used.

Comment: Alright I'm back with a response. Our team was new to the idea of SASS and was ill-guided in implementing extendable classes like this. We actually even had defects arise in older browsers (IE7,8) where a float left style wasn't inherited correctly. We have since begun to revert these changes. Thanks!

Comment: Oh god, my brain hurts. You should probably try to find a different place to work, asap. Even if your team was completely new to Sass, this is just seismically, catastrophically, apocalyptically stupid.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should only use extend when you have a certain attribute set that will be used multiple times. The sheer stupidy of extending a class with a class with one attribute that has the unit value worked into the name of it is incomprehensible.

A better example for a reason to extend can be found in the [reference guide](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend)

Say we have 2 classes

```
.error {
  border: 1px #f00;
  background-color: #fdd;
}
.seriousError {
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

`.error` is a general no interesting style but a serious error should be really clear.

`.seriousError` is created to thicken the line, the only problem is that now we have to use both classes in the html to combine the styles.

Because we're lazy and just want to use one class and not duplicate code that might be changed in the future we can extend `.seriousError` with `.error`

```
.seriousError {
  @extend .error;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

Now we didn't duplicate the code in our sass file but did get the right styles on the page.

Check out the reference guide for more/better examples.

Just please for the sake of kittens stop extending classes with one attribute classes. And don't implicitly state the value/attributes in the selector, thats not very semantic.

You, and your team, should [read this post](http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/11/css-coding-semantic-approach-in-naming.html) which explains a few problems with the aproach you take here vs semantic code. Couldn't find a better tuned post this quick.

Comment: This confirms what I was thinking, Thanks again!

Comment: @Lucas: Are you planning on sharing this post with your team? Did you ask *them* what this was for?

Comment: Hah just looking for the confirmation is dangerous, you should look for a well-balanced answer instead, though I doubt many people will disagree with me on this one.

Comment: @Madmartigan makes a good point, maybe they have a good reason to do this, and to be honest if they do I'd like to hear it too...

Comment: So extending the bootstrap's .nav.active with .bg-info and .text-white is a legit use case?

Answer (score 7):

You aren't missing anything, this is just bloated code in poor form and not a great way to extend classes.

There is maybe one (bad) reason I can imagine why this would be used. If for example `.font-10` needs to be `.7em` instead of `10px`, it can be easily changed - ***but*** then you've just defeated the point of naming the class "`font10`". Something like `small-font` would even make more sense in that case (and I'm not suggesting you use that either).

I won't discuss the merits of semantic class names and the folly of presentational ones (especially as literal as these are), but I will suggest that this is a very narrow use of extending classes. With a 1:1 mapping of class name to property/value, you've practically defeated the purpose of `@extend`, which is supposed to make you write less CSS.

Better example of what to use `@extend` for:

```
.media {
    padding:1em;
    border-color:blue;
    background-color:red;
    clear:left;
}

.my-media {
    @extend .media;
    background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Atomic CSS

The technique of very simple CSS rules does have a bit of precedent - at Yahoo! they call it Atomic CSS. Thierry Koblentz argues in [this Smashing Magazine article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/21/challenging-css-best-practices-atomic-approach/) for using the simple classes directly in your markup, similar to inline styling. This can be helpful on very large projects across multiple web properties, where styles are not consistent. Base styles for OOCSS components can't be reused as much in such a situation, causing you to have to write many more lines of extension classes or overrides.

The downside is, of course, as [Wesley mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828009/sass-when-to-extend/9828478#9828478), that it is much more difficult to make changes across your entire project's styles, such as updating the text size of a specific selector.

I've been playing around with a variant of this technique recently in a fairly large project, where styles can often be one-off. In an effort to avoid the  I try to avoid putting hard values directly in the selectors. For instance, the following css ([example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karlhorky/6reqK/)):

#### _colors.scss

```
.text-white {
  color: $white;
}

.blue {
  @extend .text-white;
  background: $blue;
}
```

#### _effects.scss

```
.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.matted {
  border: 4px solid $white;
}

.shadow {
  @include box-shadow(0 1px 4px 1px rgba($black, 0.25));
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<div class="blue matted circle shadow">?</div>
```

## Specificity issues

One last thing to keep in mind if you decide to use this technique - it can cause specificity problems if you're extending base-level classes that use the same CSS properties. For instance, in the following example ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karlhorky/yLh7N/)), how would your border-radius appear? You wanted the top to be squared off (no border-radius) but this isn't happening, because the .circle class is further down in your css and just as specific (single class) as the other effects. This is a bit of a contrived example, but if you reuse CSS properties across your atomic selectors, this can be a real problem.

#### _colors.scss

```
.text-white {
  color: white;
}

.blue {
  @extend .text-white;
  background: royalblue;
}
```

#### _effects.scss

```
.squared-top {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.rounded {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<span class="circle blue rounded squared-top"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it that way you can also use it directly in the HTML - so it looks like they took the OOCSS path and because it's already in the CSS you can now also extend to it. Very flexible but it could also turn very messy.

Answer (score 0):

Extend option is used poorly here. It should be used for extending classes with more content and in that case extend can be very helpful.You can find more about extend and its options [here](https://kolosek.com/css-extend/).